# Texas instruments C1101 RF1100 module Schematics

Tags: communication, texas-instruments, 433mhz

does anyone got schematic from this module. I tried searching around but didn't get anything except main header pin-out. There are also 2x2 pin on each corner, but there is no info about them.

[image]

Comment: The 2x2 holes are most likely to facilitate mounting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closely, you see the four small copper lines that connect the 2x2 pins to the ground plane. My multimeter confirms this: 0.4 Ohm from ground to each of the 'pins', the same reading for shorted probes.

Besides the chip there isn't much on the PCB that could be interesting: a 26 MHz crystal, a maching network for the antenna, some power decoupling. Probably a copy of the circuit on p25 of the datasheet:

[image]